# (HTML/CSS) Why wont my nav go to the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm really new to coding, and I am sure this will be answered somewhere. But everywhere I look I don't understand much. When I use `text-align: center` to align my nav, it goes underneath the line that the logo is own, as if it is stopping it moving to the top of the page. You can see it [here](https://gyazo.com/eaba3ca9089fbe173fa4416992f9d243) when I select the images.

I have tried using margins but I can not get that menu to go up. I have also tried using `display: inline` but that adds extra size to my nav and still won't hit the top of the page, as you can see [here](https://gyazo.com/2f91a0992638e891c2eebbdaf1cda68d?token=94d94dfcc818c8af44d16978d5f2cb37) when I select it.

Here's the code:

```css
head {}

body {
  background-image: url(img/background.jpg);
}

.logo {
  display: inline;
}

div.nav {
  display: inline;
}

div.content {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>LiaamB Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/icon.png" />
</head>
<a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" width=200 height="200" class="logo"></a>
<img src="img/worktitle.png" width="200" height="200">
<div class="nav">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="img/home.png" width="250" height="100"></a>
  <a href="work.html"><img src="img/work.png" width="250" height="100"></a>
  <a href="store.html"><img src="img/store.png" width="250" height="100"></a>
  <a href="contact.html"><img src="img/contact.png" width="250" height="100"></a>
  <a href="videos.html"><img src="img/videos.png" width="250" height="100"></a>
</div>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="img/about.png" width="1500" height="150">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: provide a js fiddle and I might be able to help.

Comment: Your nav div is not inside the html body.

Comment: Im not sure what a js fiddle is? im so sorry im new and have spent atleast 4 hours trying to fix this :)

Comment: You have some of the HTML code placed between 2 </head> tags. It this a mistake when pasting code in stackoverflow textbox or the main cause of the problem you mention?

Comment: just put the nav in the body and it still has spacing ontop of the nav and hasnt hit the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

Your head tag is closed twice. This should work

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>LiaamB Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>   
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/icon.png"/>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" width=200 height="200" class="logo"></a>
    <img src="img/worktitle.png" width="200" height="200">
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/home.png" width="250" height="100"></a>
        <a href="work.html"><img src="img/work.png" width="250" height="100"></a>
        <a href="store.html"><img src="img/store.png" width="250" height="100"></a>
        <a href="contact.html"><img src="img/contact.png" width="250" height="100"></a> 
        <a href="videos.html"><img src="img/videos.png" width="250" height="100"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    <img src="img/about.png" width="1500" height="150">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whew. I missed the two head tags bit. thanks for this. but i tried both the codes and there is still added spacing on top of the nav like it is the same height as the logo. and wont hit the top of the page :(

Answer (score 0):

Like @hairmot said, you have your `<div class="nav">` element outside of your `body`.  You also have two closing `</head>` tags.  Fixing those two errors should resolve your issue.

Here is your code with those two problems fixed:

```css
head {}

body {
  background-image: url(img/background.jpg);
}

.logo {
  display: inline;
}

div.nav {
  display: inline;
}

div.content {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>LiaamB Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/icon.png" />
</head>

<body>
  <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" width=200 height="200" class="logo"></a>
  <img src="img/worktitle.png" width="200" height="200">
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/home.png" width="250" height="100"></a>
    <a href="work.html"><img src="img/work.png" width="250" height="100"></a>
    <a href="store.html"><img src="img/store.png" width="250" height="100"></a>
    <a href="contact.html"><img src="img/contact.png" width="250" height="100"></a>
    <a href="videos.html"><img src="img/videos.png" width="250" height="100"></a>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <img src="img/about.png" width="1500" height="150">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: its still adding spacing https://gyazo.com/763e4cfd24b250ee66a745faf1294581

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys :) i think i will just add margins on the logo and work title to make it inline with the nav. Then just deal with spacing at the top of the page :) Thanks once again.